# Why Hadoop 2.6.4 is released after 2.7.2

Tags: hadoop

[Apache Hadoop Release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbTkf.png)

I downloaded Hadoop 2.6.4, but I find 2.7.2 was released earlier than 2.6.4, also 2.7.2 is stable. How can 2.7.2 is more stable than 2.6.4, and how can 2.7.2 released earlier than 2.6.4 ?
I guess 2.7.X are stable versions, 2.6.X are unstable versions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadoop community had decided to drop JDK6 runtime and works with JDK 7+ only.
On 2.x release versions they started this trough release 2.7.0.
To extend support for JDK6 hadoop users they started maintenance release for 2.6.x branch.

**Summary**

- 2.7.x versions contains roadmap features with JDK7 support.
- 2.6.x version contains point releases having critical fixes with JDK6 support.

To answer the question 2.6.x release post 2.7.x are point releases for 2.6.x branch containing critical fixes.

As long as stability is concerned, release 2.7.1 and 2.7.2 are stable.

**Sources**

http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html

Check POM configuration of Hadoop's 2.7.x & 2.6.x branches on github mirrors for JDK compatibility